# Laravel: Add global scope to Models if a certain middleware is run

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to enable a global scope based on if a middleware is applied or not?

I have a global scope I would like to enable for a certain part of my site and disable on the rest (customer vs admin area) and I'm thinking if you can do this by checking if a middleware "EnableGlobalScopeMiddleware" has run or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, create the middleware `EnableGlobalScopeMiddleware`

```
php artisan make:middleware EnableGlobalScopeMiddleware
```

and apply the global scope to the model(s) in the `handle` function

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EnableGlobalScopeMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        Model::addGlobalScope('foo', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('foo', 'bar');
        });

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Register the middleware in `App\Http\Kernel` by adding it to the protected `$routeMiddleware` array property

```php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'global' => \App\Http\Middleware\EnableGlobalScopeMiddleware::class, // <-- Here
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];
```

And apply to it to the specific routes, for example `/admin` prefix routes group

```php
Route::middleware(['global'])->prefix('admin')->group(function () {
    // Routes here
});
```

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I didnt think about the fact that you can replace static::globalScope with a class name.

Comment: Calling static inside the class is the same as calling the class outside of it